# 5mm RGB Led built in IC

Tags: led, timer, control, driver, flipflop

[image]

Is there any standalone IC do the same job this 5mm Led (standalone flasher and builtin control IC)  does?

Comment: And what "job" would that be, exactly? What do you want the device to do? How would the device be any different than what you have pictured? Your little photograph is not very informative.

Comment: It's plenty clear. The ic flashes through the colors slowly.

Comment: @Passerby It's not clear what the operating voltage range is. It's not clear how much current is supplied to each LED. It's not clear what "slow" means. It's not clear how the OP expects to physically assemble the IC and the LEDs. And it's certainly not clear that a typical microcontroller could do the "job".

Comment: it's clear what my question is!

Comment: I hope you got the answer you wanted...use a microcontroller.

Comment: @Elliot so your saying a typical microcontroller can't fade in and out a gpio? And you don't understand what slow is? Clearly speak english, so you know what slow is...

Comment: @Passerby What I'm saying is that a typical microcontroller won't operate at, say, 9V and a typical microcontroller won't supply, say, 50mA on an output pin. What I'm saying is that the OP didn't provide any indication that the example device did PWM fading. Is any of that what is required to do the "job"? I don't know, and I think the OP should have added more information to clarify what they were looking for. Does "slowly" mean over 0.5s or 50s? I don't think I was out of line asking for more information.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IC used inside these specialty leds are very very difficult to find outside of chinese street markets and you'd have to be pretty good at understanding chinese to find them. They are often not found in "regular" sizes. The specific ones used are wire bond, the size of a pin head.

That said, this is nothing that can't be done with a general purpose microcontroller. All it does is cycle through a routine, and doesn't need anything other than a few pwm routines or 3 pwm channels.

Comment: I _suspect_ the OP doesn't care how easy it is to do with a programmable part, he just wants to buy a thing that works without "added value" operations like writing a program. Nevermind the fact that _once_ you write a program and generate a binary for it, you can get some manufacturers, and otherwise distributors, to sell you the controller pre-programmed with your custom firmware...

Comment: Passerby: Thank you for your answer,  I know it is hard to find it but I thought someone could know where to find one in general,  the way I wanted that IC because these RGB Leds described above are 0.017 dollars dirt cheap,  so if I found an IC do the same work at the same price or so,  I could hook some transistor to it make it commercially available here in my town. Thanks although